# Get Google token through .NET Web API, error redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to authenticate user with Google login, I am getting the authorization code from frontend, and I want to trade it for access token with Google.

This is my code:

```
[Route("google")]
public object Google(AuthModel model) {
    IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets {
            ClientId = model.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = Constants.Constants.GOOGLE_SECRET
        },
        Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" }
    });
    var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("", model.Code, "postmessage",
                    CancellationToken.None).Result;
    return token.AccessToken;
}
```

When  calling method `flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` I am getting error

```
{"Error:\"redirect_uri_mismatch\", Description:\"\", Uri:\"\""}
```

I do not understand, where I can define a redirect URL? I have spend multiple hours of googleing the issue and answers all say that I should define some URLs in my google application account, where I have at the moment:

```
Redirect URIs   
http://localhost:53906
http://localhost:53906/authcallback
```

Comment: The third parameter of [ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1Flows_1_1AuthorizationCodeFlow#ae800a73ce82d01e0329e19cc68b02a2c) should be the redirect URI, I don't think `postmessage` is the value you want to be using.

Comment: Look in the developer console to define the redirect uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client library detects on its own where you are sending your request from.  So you don't need to apply it.    You tell Google which redirect URIs you will be using from the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com).  It appears you have done that.

Your issue is probably that Visual studio has a habit of randomly changing the port number.  You can either fix this in your project settings.

OR

Go to Google Developer Console. Create a `Client ID for native application` use this client id while you are testing on localhost.  Once you release to production website change back to a `Client ID for web application`

The reason this works is `Client ID for native application` allows connection from all locations so it wont matter if Visual studio changes your port.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only thing that worked was putting same url parameter for TokenResponse as it was for Credentials. Nothing else worked - I've tried 'postmessage' as url, then urls to some other actions on my site, even without url. Nothing worked.

When I've typed same url as it was for credentials, it worked like a charm.

Code:

```
ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
ClientId = "***",
ClientSecret = "***"
};
IEnumerable<string> scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail, PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile };

IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
     ClientSecrets = secrets,
     Scopes = scopes
});                               

TokenResponse token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("", code, 
"https://localhost:44388/TestLogin/Redirect", //This is the same url that I have for credentials
   CancellationToken.None).Result;
```